# Crontab not opening gnome-terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

Configured crontab to run a script.

crontab config

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0 && sh $HOME/path/to/script >> /tmp/error.llog 2>&1
```

Script

```
gnome-terminal --window -e "sudo ifconfig wlo1 down; sleep 1; sudo ifconfig wlo1 up"
```

Whenever the script is executed I'm getting the following error message.

> Error constructing proxy for org.gnome.Terminal:/org/gnome/Terminal/Factory0: Could not connect: Connection refused

Locale configs

> LANG=en_IN
> LANGUAGE=en_IN:en
> LC_CTYPE="en_IN"
> LC_NUMERIC="en_IN"
> LC_TIME="en_IN"
> LC_COLLATE="en_IN"
> LC_MONETARY="en_IN"
> LC_MESSAGES="en_IN"
> LC_PAPER="en_IN"
> LC_NAME="en_IN"
> LC_ADDRESS="en_IN"
> LC_TELEPHONE="en_IN"
> LC_MEASUREMENT="en_IN"
> LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_IN"
> LC_ALL=

Comment: Comments indicate that this "script is working on the ubuntu 21.04 machine but it is not working on a 16.04 machine". Debugging an EOL system is out of scope of the site.

Answer (score 1):

You really do not want to open Gnome Terminal this way. Cron is not designed to be used for starting graphical applications. Use "autostart"  in your desktop environment to automatically open a terminal emulator.

Comment: It is a time-triggered script and so I'm using crontab. The script is working on the ubuntu 21.04 machine but it is not working on a 16.04 machine

Comment: Does your question relate to Ubuntu 16.04? That looks a pretty old version to me for which the site does not anymore give support.

Comment: Yes, the Ubuntu version is 16.04. The site doesn't give any support but the crontab should work right?